# Use Office365 account to Administer Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

We have an Office365 and Azure subscription.  The Azure subscription was created first and uses a Microsoft account to administer it.  We would like to use the accounts setup in Office365 to assign permission on the Azure subscription.  As Office365 uses Azure AD this should be possible?  However I'm not sure how to configure it and I haven't found any helpful articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure subscriptions are always linked to an Azure AD.
In order to administrate the subscriptions, the user must be a member or guest of that directory.

Option 1: Add the O365 users as guests in your AAD that is currently linked.

Option 2: Switch the directory linked to your subscription to the O365 directory.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly, if not let me know please!
Your Office 365 accounts are hosted in Azure AD, that's correct.

I would suggest looking into RBAC (Role Based Access Control). This allows you to granularly give permissions/rights in Azure without giving out too much access.

[Here's more info about RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)

You can easily assign roles in Azure itself, using the O365 accounts.

If you got more questions, lemme know! :)